# R-Creating a New Column Based On Positions Specified by an Existing Column

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataset (df) looks like this.

```
A   B   C   D   E   Position    
67  68  69  70  71   5           
20  21  22  23  24   2           
98  97  96  95  94   3           
2   5   7   9   12   5           
4   8   12  16  20   4
```

I am trying  to create a new column (`Result`) where the value of result is equal to the position of the column specified in the `position` column for each row of the resulting column.

For example, if the row 1 of `position` column is 5, the `Result` column will have the value of 5th column of row 1.

My resulting column will look like this:

```
     A   B  C   D   E   Position    Result
    67  68  69  70  71   5           71
    20  21  22  23  24   2           21
    98  97  96  95  94   3           96
    2   5   7   9   12   5           12
    4   8   12  16  20   4           16
```

I used the following command, which does not give me what I need. It lumps all of the `position` column values in each row. I am unable to determine how I can get the correct result.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you could try: `t(df[,-6])[df$Position+0:4*5]#[1] 71 21 96 12 16`

Comment: For this example, you can use `df$Result <- diag(as.matrix(df[, df$Position]))`, not sure about the bigger data set though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use matrix indexing to extract the values:

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$Position)]
# [1] 71 21 96 12 16
```

Assign the result in the normal way:

```
df$Result <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$Position)]
```